# I can not "pich" the dates e "put" in other sheet! (copy and paste)

Tags: vba, excel

I prefer to use the function .value, because i dont miss anything, but i cant to paste or the all range

Anyone know how i can do?

```
Sub AUTO()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'sheet that i want paste
PasteData1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6).Value
DATAAUTO = "L:\ANALISTA_M\Frade\FINANCIAL SERVICES\INSURANCE\Mercado\SUSEP\Planilhas\Auto-Susep.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open (DATAAUTO)
sName = ActiveSheet.Name

'count the number of rows and columns
i = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 11
c = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'select all range that i want
COPYDATE = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(i, c)).Value


PASTEAUTO = "L:\ANALISTA_M\Frade\FINANCIAL SERVICES\INSURANCE\Mercado\SUSEP\Auto.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open (PASTEAUTO)
Worksheets(PasteData1).Activate

'the problem is here!!! i need to respect a order the beging my paste
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = COPYDATE

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(i - 4, c + 1)).Replace What:=".", Replacement:=""
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(i - 4, c + 1)).Replace What:=",", Replacement:="."

Worksheets("Consolidado").Activate

Workbooks("Auto-Susep.xlsx").Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

to use the `.Value` over copy paste you need to have the same size range.  You have one cell trying to hold a 2 dimensional array.

So change:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = COPYDATE
```

to:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(COPYDATE,1),UBound(COPYDATE,2)).Value = COPYDATE
```

Also I do not see where you declare any of your variables, that is a bad habit, one should always declare their variables even if they are of a Variant type.

```
Dim COPYDATE() as Variant
```

Comment: One more thing, Scott

I was curious. I didnt understand why it is so important to declare the variable, because the code works even i didnt declare